# Sum multiple rows using columns as criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum multiple rows using column headers as criteria but keep coming up blank.
[In this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ1Sw.png), the range that needs to be summed is D2:F4 but ultimately I'll be summing arbitrary, contiguous date ranges.

All help greatly appreciated. Thanks!
(Sorry no rep yet to post pics)

To return data from the current week (based on Rory's solution):

`=SUMPRODUCT((B1:1>=(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1))*(B1:1<=(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+5))*(B2:4))`

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT - eg `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:Z1>=DATE(2021,9,1))*(B1:Z1<=DATE(2021,9,30))*(B2:Z4))`

Comment: It's beautiful. Thanks... If only my little brain could understand how multiplication leads to a sum!!! Put your answer below so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` for this - eg:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:Z1>=DATE(2021,9,1))*(B1:Z1<=DATE(2021,9,30))*(B2:Z4))
```

to sum data for September of this year.

Comment: Thanks Rory. Added another formula to the orig question that returns the sum for the current week.